# Проблема с компиляцией

Tags: python

У меня есть код. Он ищет максимальный элемент в списке, а потом должен выводить элементы в порядке убывания. Но код не компилируется. В чем может быть проблема?

```
import random

spisok = []

for i in range(0,5):
    spisok.append(random.randint(1,25))



a = 0
for i in range(0,5):
    if spisok[i] > a:
        a = spisok[i]

print('Such numbers are generated: ')
print(spisok)
print('In decreasing order: ')
print(a)

for num, i in enumerate(a, 1):
    print('{cout} maximum: {maxim}'.format(maxim = i, cout = num))
```

Ошибка такая:

```
for num, i in enumerate(a, 1): 
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас должно быть:

```
enumerate(range(0, 1))
```

И вот наш код целиком:

```
from random import randint

spisok = [randint(1, 25) for i in range(5)]


print('Such numbers are generated: ')
print(spisok) #[7, 1, 6, 2, 11]
print('In decreasing order: ')
print(max(spisok)) #11

spisok = sorted(spisok, reverse=True)
print(spisok) #[11, 7, 6, 2, 1]
```

Если через цикл, то можно так:

```
sort_list = list()

for i in range(5):
   sort_list.append(max(spisok))
   spisok.pop(spisok.index(max(spisok)))
   spisok.append(0)


print(sort_list)  #[11, 7, 6, 2, 1]
```

Comment: А можете подсказать, как это сделать в циклах, не используя sorted?

Comment: могу, но нужна ли вам эта морока?

Comment: Нужна, к сожалению(

Comment: дополнил ответ, думаю, так нормально будет

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что в enumerate нужно передавать список, а не число (`а`).

И вообще непонятно для чего нужна часть

```
for num, i in enumerate(a, 1):
    print('{cout} maximum: {maxim}'.format(maxim = i, cout = num))
```